# Allow CXF webservice receive XML as string - CDATA

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, cxf

I am tasked to develop a webservice proxy which implement the same wsdl as the target webservice (original webservice). My problem is, the "String_1" field contains xml string, e.g. `<String_1>xml string here...</String_1>`, which contains angle brackets ("<>").

According to xsd:string, the correct behavior would be throwing error. I used wsdl2java to generate code, and it works as expected.

However, the target webservice can accept the message without throwing exception, e.g. treat the `"<dummy />"` as string.

I want to know how to bypass the validation check? Or perhaps override some interceptors to add `"<!CDATA"` in the payload?

I have tried setting the parameters as below, but it only throws different kind of exception:

```
   <jaxws:properties>     
      <entry key="faultStackTraceEnabled" value="true" />
      <entry key="exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" value="true" />
      <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
      <entry key="set-jaxb-validation-event-handler" value="false" />  
   </jaxws:properties>
```

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:man="http://mantra.com/mantraws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <man:getList>

         <String_1><dummy/></String_1>

      </man:getList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

WSDL:

```
<part name='String_1' type='xsd:string'></part>
```

Response:

```
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"dummy"). Expected elements are (none)</faultstring>
     <detail> ... </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
```

Comment: If you want to treat xml as string, I believe CDATA is the only way.

Comment: I have implemented an interceptor at Phase.RECEIVE to wrap all the values with CDATA block.

Comment: Great. For future reference could you provide your implementation? Is it something like this http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/CXF-jaxb-send-string-as-CData-td5524523.html ?

Comment: I have posted my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my implementation. I know there's a lot of places need to be improved (e.g. efficiency of using "replaceAll()" methods). Please kindly let me know if there's any better implementation.

```
   public class CDATAInInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
            public CDATAInInterceptor() {
                super(Phase.RECEIVE);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                message.put(Message.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);

                if (is != null) {
                    CachedOutputStream cos = new CachedOutputStream();
                    try {
                        IOUtils.copy(is, cos);
                        String soapMessage = new String(cos.getBytes());
                        cos.flush();
                        cos.close();
                        is.close();

                        // escape the content by wrapping it with CDATA block
                        // hard coded tag name that contains xml string
                        String newSoapMessage = escapeContent(soapMessage, new String[]{"tag_1", "tag_2"});

                        InputStream newIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(newSoapMessage.getBytes());
                        message.setContent(InputStream.class, newIs);

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            // this methods will wrap "CDATA" around content of supplied tagNames
            private String escapeContent(final String xmlString, String[] tagNames) {
                String newXmlString = xmlString;

                for (String tagName : tagNames) {

                    // start tag
                    newXmlString = newXmlString.replaceAll("<" + tagName + ">", "<"+ tagName + "><![CDATA[");
                    // close tag
                    newXmlString = newXmlString.replaceAll("</" + tagName + ">", "]]></" + tagName + ">");
                }

                return newXmlString;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can select your own answer as the solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to wait to see if someone can provide a better solution.